# Trying to understand this code (Batch, CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

> ```
>     @echo off
> setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
> ::just a sample adapter here:
> set "adapter=Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection"
> set adapterfound=false
> echo Network Connection Test
> for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig /all`) do 
> (
>     set "item=%%f"
>     if /i "!item!"=="!adapter!" 
>   (
>         set adapterfound=true
>       )
>    else if not "!item!"=="!item:IP Address=!" if "!adapterfound!"=="true" 
>   (
>         echo Your IP Address is: %%g
>         set adapterfound=false
>       )
> )
> ```

VERY new to batch, can someone explain a few things here:

1. What does setlocal enabledelayedexpansion do in this particular instance?
2. What does usebackq do? (I've tried looking this up but didn't quite understand)
3. How did the variable %%g get initialized and is it global or local?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Actually the script cannot work as there are some syntax errors: `for ... do (`, `if ... (`, `) else` (the parenthesis must not be placed in a separate line!)

Comment: I recommend reading the [Stack Overflow batch-file Documentation pages](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/topics).

Answer (score 2):

1. **Delayed Expansion** will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
   Code below would seem to echo `second second`, but it prints `first second` instead.

   ```
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set var=first
    set var=second & Echo %var% !var!
   ```

   Source: [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
2. `usebackq` forces for loops use backquotes (`` `dir` ``) to evaluate the commands inside it and use the output for the `for`loop, instead of open a file. This will list all elements of Documents predeced with an asterisk.

   ```
   echo Documents:
   for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b "C:\Users\%username%\Documents\"`) do (
     echo * %%i
   )
   pause
   ```
3. They're local. Using the previous example, `%%i`is defined just in the `for` loop, no additional initialization needed.

Comment: I still don't understand how the %%g variable became initialized with the IP address though, how does that work and how can I store it in a global variable?. Also, what is the benefit to the delayed expansion, why did this person decide to implement this code like that? Great explanation on everything though, thank you!

Comment: Without `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, the `item` variable would not have a value until the loop had completed because it was initialized inside of the `for` loop. `%%g` was created by the `tokens=1-2` bit of the loop. That bit declares **two** variables, and since you started with `%%f`, the character with the next-highest ASCII value is `%%g`. I have no idea why `usebackq` was used; there's no reason it to be there beyond personal preference.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how it actually got it's value. First mention of it is just the echo.